# If $f$ is Lebesgue integrable, is $f^2$ also Lebesgue integrable?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Is there an example where $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable but $f^2$ isn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try for example
$$
\matrix{(0,1] & \longrightarrow & {\bf R} \cr
             x    & \mapsto & {1\over \sqrt{x}} \cr}
$$